# Finding time complexity with trees and recursion

Tags: algorithm, recursion

Am I right in thinking this is O(n)? I'm really bad at recursion. Could someone please confirm, or explain to me?

```
Counter(a)
    if hasLeft(a)
        return Counter(left(a) + Counter (right(a))
    else
        return 1
```

Basically, if there isn't a left node in the tree, it returns 0. If there are left notes, it returns 1.

Thanks!

Comment: If your intention is truly to return 0 or 1 based on no left node / a left node, you can make an O(1) routine pretty easily and no need for recursion. Beyond that, it's really not clear what you're trying to accomplish but it feels like your code example is flawed (if !hasLeft(a) .... recurse based on left(a)... when you've already determined there is no left branch.

Comment: Sorry - I fixed it. I didn't mean to have the !
I'm just trying to understand recursion and time complexity here, using this specific code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's (binary) tree, because there isn't any loop in graph, it just check each node at most one time so it's `O(n)`.

Comment: I just reduced the algorithm, and forgot to delete the h. I'll edit it out. I thought it was O(n) - thanks for the confirmation + explanation!

Comment: @Kris, If this is your answer, toggle check box in the left hand of answer to green.

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't do what's advertised. You said you want it to return 1 if there is a left node, and 0 if there is not a left node. But your code is:

```
Counter(a)
    if hasLeft(a)
        return Counter(left(a)) + Counter(right(a))
    else
        return 1
```

This returns 1 if there is no left node at the root, but it doesn't check the rest of the tree. This code will not examine the entire tree, but rather will stop at the first level that has no left node.

What are you really trying to do?

Comment: His question is about running time not code is right or not. and this answer can be a comment. null checking,... are another notes.

Comment: @Saeed: I understand that, but it's pretty difficult to give the running time for code that doesn't work.

Comment: you can assume this is a pseudo code, and it works without your recommendation (but he should add null checking), but may be it doesn't work as he want, but it's an algorithm and has a running time.